# Looking to append a tab separated line from word to excel with a macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, macros, csv

Or something....
Word is integrated with our software so it does only one account at a time.

Each tab separated line is formatted like:
name address acct# dob amtdue

For each account I have to load up a fresh word document, copy paste the values into an existing excel sheet, and send it on its way.

This is a lot of button pushing for me, any way to automate this?
I have made a couple simple macros w/o having to program anything.

I have the following versions of ...stuff

Excel 2002 10.6501.6714 SP3
Word 2002 10.6612.6714 SP3
Visual Basic Editor: VB 6.3 v.9969 VBA Retail 6.4.8869
MS Script Editor 10.0

Comment: your question doesn't make much sense  . data doesn't pull anything. I guess you mean you want some macro to grab the contents of a bunch of word documents and paste them into an excel document. I don't know much about macros, but should be possible.

Comment: Ya that's what I mean, will edit OP. I type faster than I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt something like this. Right now it selects the whole word doc into a new workbook. You could paste into a template workbook, or your existing sheet location instead, and be more selective in word as well, but you get the idea.

```
Sub paste2excel()
Selection.WholeStory
Selection.Copy
Dim excelObj As Object
Set excelObj = CreateObject("excel.application")
excelObj.Visible = True
excelObj.Workbooks.Add
excelObj.Range("a1").Select
excelObj.ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

this works in office 2003 and probably will be fine in your version